# SerialPort StopBits Windows7 C++/CLI

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, serial-port

I've been using the `SerialPort` class from C++/CLI (`Windows::IO::Ports`) to open a serial port and communicate with a periferic device, and everything seems to work. The port opens, and the data is sent.. But i didn't get an answer from the periferic device.

I use a code like:

```cpp
SerialPort^ _serialPort;
_serialPort = gcnew SerialPort();

//_serialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM1",115200,Parity::None, 8, StopBits::One);

// Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
_serialPort->PortName = "COM1";
_serialPort->BaudRate = 115200;

//Parity None by default
//_serialPort->Parity = Parity::None;

_serialPort->DataBits = 8;

_serialPort->StopBits = StopBits::One;

// Set the read/write timeouts
_serialPort->ReadTimeout = 1000;
_serialPort->WriteTimeout = 500;
_serialPort->Open();
```

Using a program to monitor the Serial Port communication, it seems that the number of Stop bits is 0. As you can see, i set the stop bits to 1, and even the strangest thing is that the default value is 1. I don't know why it keeps being 0. I have tried to change the baudrate and the databits, and it is changed, but there is no way with the StopBits...

It is really a pitty, because this seems really easier to use that other codes around the web.

Can anybody help me? Any ideas why it didn't work?

---

Can anybody tell me then, if this code is ok?

the array sent is: `array<Byte>^ bytes = gcnew array<Byte>(32);` (it is initialized with some values)

to send data i use: `_serialPort->Write(bytes,0,32);`

To read data i have tried:

```cpp
_serialPort->Read(readarray,0,18);
_serialPort->ReadExisting();
```

And none of them get back any data... When i use the Serial Port Monitor to open the communication and send the same bytes, it answers...

Comment: What monitor program have you used. How have you verified that there are zero stop bits unless you are capturing the signals from the port? As to Ben Voigt's answer, you maybe don't use the DCB but perhaps the monitor program you are using does and that is why it displays zero.

Comment: Do you mean a ["Prolific" chipset](http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/products.asp?id=59)?

Comment: I downloaded Serial Port Monitor 4.0 to check it (I work with serial ports a bit too, it's always handy to see other software :) and if I open a serial port from a bog standard serial terminal application with stop bits set to one stop bit then Serial Port Monitor shows "StopBits - 0". If I open it with two stop bits then SMP4.0 shows "StopBits - 2". So it does look like it is showing the DCB value.

Comment: +1 for downloading and testing with the sniffer in question

Comment: What device are you communicating with? Can you post the code where you write your data to the device?

Answer (score 1):

The stop bits are configured by an enumerated value which is not equal to the number of stop bits.

Zero is the correct encoding for one stop bit.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363214.aspx

Comment: But i do not use the DCB Structure to set the bitstops. I use the property that is in the "SerialPort" reference: StopBits [StopBits link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.stopbits.aspx).

Should it work when i use this structure? How should i the stop bits set?

Comment: @Vic: Of course a DCB structure is used to set stop bits, it's the only way the Win32 API provides.  You just happen to be calling a wrapper function, that translates from .NET `StopBits` enumeration to the Win32 DCB settings.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!! It seems that even setting the "Handshake" to "None", the DTR and RTS ports were set LOW after the data is sent. (i don't know why).

I set them manually to HIGH with:

```
_serialPort->RtsEnable = true;
_serialPort->DtrEnable =true;
```